# "default-like" property on non-indexed fields

Tags: vb.net

I have input data that contains strings that represent dates. These may be date strings like "2000-01-01", but they might say "5Y", meaning "five years". So I have a small class to keep track of these...

```
Public Class FlexDate
    Friend Input As String = ""
    Friend Value As DateTime = EarliestDate
...
```

You might find one of these FlexDates inside a Rent object, like "myRent.StartDate". The "problem" is that I would like the Value to be accessed as the field name. For instance...

```
 myRent.StartDate.Input - returns a string
 myRent.StartDate.Value - returns a DateTime
```

So what about....

```
 myRent.StartDate - myRent.StartDate.Value
```

Is there any way to do this? It's sort of like a default property in a way, but with no index, so I don't think you can use that mechanism in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the default property using the `DefaultMemberAttribute`:

```
<System.Reflection.DefaultMember("Value")> _
Public Class FlexDate
    '...
End Class
```

But this won't help you in VB, because you can't access it. It is just ambiguous - do you mean the object or its property.

But you can implement an implicit conversion:

```
Class FlexDate
    '...
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(this As FlexDate) As DateTime
        Return this.Value
    End Operator
End Class

Dim date As New FlexDate
Dim value As DateTime = date 'Works with the implicit operator
```

Comment: Nico, this response led me down a rabbit hole that I clearly should have gone down long ago. Operators are cool! But one problem/question: the method signature above does not work inside code like Format(myRent.StartDate...). I can fix this with a CDate inside the Format, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. What's a `CDate` and what format are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry Nico, I should have been more clear: the data in question is a DateTime object, as you noted in your reply. So if the call to FlexDate is from a method that takes a DateTime, it works fine. However, if the call is from a polymorphic method, like Format, the runtime can't decide what conversion to call. If you wrap it like CDate(myRent.FlexDate) then the runtime figures it out, but this *may* defeat the purpose.

Comment: In the `Format` case it's probably more reasonable to override the `ToString()` method of `FlexDate`. Apart from this, you can always use the `Value` directly as in `Format(myRent.FlexDate.Value)`.